# BinarySearch on List<T> seems to be returning strange result

Tags: c#, collections, binary-search

I am very new to C#. I have created a List object and then I am performing BinarySearch on a particular item. But the search results seem to strange. Here is the code :

```
class Element
{
    public int x;
    public Element(int val) { x = val; }
}
class MyContainer : IComparable<MyContainer>
{
    public Element elem;
    public MyContainer(int val) { elem = new Element(val); }
    public MyContainer(Element e) { elem = e; }
    public int CompareTo(MyContainer obj)
    {
        if (elem.x < obj.elem.x) { return -1; }
        else if (elem.x == obj.elem.x) { return 0; }
        else { return 1; }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyContainer container1 = new MyContainer(100);
        MyContainer container2 = new MyContainer(21);
        MyContainer container3 = new MyContainer(-122);
        Element elemObj = new Element(-122);

        List<MyContainer> list = new List<MyContainer>();
        list.Add(new MyContainer(80));
        list.Add(container1);
        list.Add(container2);
        list.Add(container3);
        list.Add(new MyContainer(90));
        foreach(MyContainer c in list)  Console.WriteLine(c.elem.x);

        if (list.Contains(container3) == true) Console.WriteLine("present");
        else Console.WriteLine("NOT present");
        Console.WriteLine("Search result:::"+list.BinarySearch(new MyContainer(elemObj)));
        Console.WriteLine("Search result:::" + list.BinarySearch(container1));
        Console.WriteLine("Search result:::" + list.BinarySearch(container2));
        Console.WriteLine("Search result:::" + list.BinarySearch(container3));
    }
}
```

The output is as follows :

```
80
100
21
-122
90
present
Search result:::-1
Search result:::-6
Search result:::2
Search result:::-1
```

Why is only the element corresponding to value 21 found and why not the others

Answer (score 9):

Your list isn't sorted to start with. Binary search *only* works when the original input is sorted. The whole point is that you know that if `list[x] = y`, then `list[a] <= y` for all `a < x` and `list[a] >= y` for all `a > x`.

So either you need to sort your list first, or you need to choose a different way of searching (e.g. using a separate hash-based dictionary, or just doing a linear search).

Also note that your `CompareTo` method can be implemented a lot more simply:

```
public int CompareTo(MyContainer obj)
{
    return elem.x.CompareTo(obj.elem.x);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only works on a sorted list. Since your list is not sorted in the way it should be, it may or may not find the result correctly. You could fix this by [sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) first:

```
list.Add(new MyContainer(90));
// after adding all elements
list.Sort();
foreach(MyContainer c in list)  Console.WriteLine(c.elem.x);
```